# AngularJS: what is the execution order among link, controller and compile functions in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain which part of the code will execute first? (link or compile or controller) and what will be the exact order of execution?

Comment: please try searching before asking...there are numerous answers to this already and they are easily found. There are even matches on right side of this page under **Related**